# Why is my const not being exported?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file called `style.js` with the following content:

```
const CenterStyle = {
  width: 800,
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  marginLeft: 300,
  marginTop: 100
}

export { CenterStyle };
```

I have a `skills.js` file with the following contents:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CenterSyle } from './style';

class Skills extend React.Component
.....React code......
```

and then finally in my `App.js` file I import the whole `Skills` class:

```
import Skills from './skills'
```

The problem I'm getting is that in my `skills.js`, my `CenterStyle` const is `undefined`. It's not being imported. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: can you try to just add export before the const

`export const CenterStyle = {yourStuffHere}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things

Either you can try to use export before const as

```
export const CenterStyle = {
  width: 800,
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  marginLeft: 300,
  marginTop: 100
}
```

and import it as

```
import { CenterSyle } from './style';
```

or

have a default export

```
const CenterStyle = {
  width: 800,
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  marginLeft: 300,
  marginTop: 100
}

export default CenterStyle ;
```

and import it as

```
import CenterSyle from './style';
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
export const CenterStyle = {
  width: 800,
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  marginLeft: 300,
  marginTop: 100
}
```

And then in your Skills import it as :

```
import { CenterSyle } from './style';
```